# Which limits are preserved by a reflective left-adjoint?

Tags: ct.category-theory

This question is closely related to this one: [Which limits are preserved by prolongation of presheaves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96342/which-limits-are-preserved-by-prolongation-of-presheaves)

Suppose that $r:C \hookrightarrow D$ is a full and faithful functor and $l:D \to C$ is a left-adjoint. Can we say when a given left-exact functor $G:D \to D$ has $l \circ G \circ r$ also left-exact?

I'm ok with assuming here that D is complete and cocomplete (and hence so is C).

Comment: Well, it's true for *all* $G$ if and only if $l$ is left-exact...

Comment: True, but in my case, I know for certain that my functor $l$ is not left-exact, since I can exhibit an equalizer it does not preserve. However, I only want it to preserve certain equalizers, and my counterexample is not among them. If it helps, in my case, I know that $l$ does preserve finite products.